# Плагин Qip Smiles смайлы подпрыгнули

Tags: css, wordpress

Установил на ВордПресс плагин Qip Smiles, позволяющий добавлять смайлы в комментарии. Но смайлы отображаются в рамочках и подпрыгнули над строчкой. Возможно ли устранение этой ошибки? [вот пример](http://hozjajstvo.ru/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлик style.css 986 строка .art-article img, img.art-article, margin и border поставьте 0.
Т.е. у вас там должно быть так:

```
.art-article img, img.art-article {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Теперь все нормально.

Comment: @alevit, пожалуйста, примите ответ (галочка слева).

Comment: Да-да, не забывайте :)

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо. Вроде разобрался как принимать, галочка стала зеленой.